# StringBuilder in inlined C# in PowerShell (2.0 and above)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, namespaces, pinvoke

The C# I am trying to inline is at the bottom, but my error is occurring at the second DllImport, because StringBuilder is not loaded. I have tried a number of things with regards to loading assemblies, adding Using references in the C#, etc. This being one example. But nothing is working and I am pretty sure I am just missing something very obvious to C# programmers, and totally non obvious to my brain.

```
$assemblies = ('mscorlib.dll')

$code = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

public static class PxTest
{
    // Note
}
'@

Add-Type -memberDefinition $code -referencedAssemblies $assemblies -namespace Px -name Test -errorAction stop
```

I have also tried `$assemblies = ('system.text')` which then tries to load system.text.dll that isn't found. Which is what sent me to the dll above, which is where StringBuilder is found I believe.

C# code to ultimately use

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

    public static bool PinUnpinTaskbar(string filePath, bool pin)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
        int MAX_PATH = 255;
        var actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
        StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
        LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
        string localizedVerb = szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();

        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        // create the shell application object
        dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
        dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
        dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);

        dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();
        for (int i = 0; i < verbs.Count(); i++)
        {
            dynamic verb = verbs.Item(i);
            if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
            {
                verb.DoIt();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: Trying to understand the edits. I get the added tags, but replacing some body text with... the same text? That I don't get. And that's at least what I am seeing. **StringBuilder is** is replaced with ***StringBuilder is***, etc. huh?

Answer (score 4):

It is because `StringBuilder` is not fully qualified and / or the namespace `System.Text` is not used

So either change the parameter to

```
System.Text.StringBuilder lpBuffer
```

or add the `UsingNamespace` parameter to the `Add-Type` cmdlet

```
Add-Type -memberDefinition $code -referencedAssemblies $assemblies -namespace Px -UsingNamespace 'System.Text' -name Test -errorAction stop
```

---

As your environment is fixed to PoSh 2.0 and Win7 I rewrote the code to handle the dynamic stuff via PowerShell (which is anyway more idiomatic in this case) and to get the localized verb via the C# code you provided so finally it looks like this which provides you a convenient PowerShell function `PinUnpinTaskbar`

```
$assemblies = ('mscorlib.dll')
$code = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

    public static string GetLocalizedPinToStartVerb(bool pin)
    {
        int MAX_PATH = 255;
        int actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
        StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
        LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
        return szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();
    }
'@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code `
         -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies `
         -Namespace Px `
         -UsingNamespace 'System.Text' `
         -Name Helper `
         -ErrorAction stop

function PinUnpinTaskbar([string]$FilePath, [boolean]$Pin) {
    if (Test-Path $FilePath) {
        $localizedVerb = [Px.Helper]::GetLocalizedPinToStartVerb($Pin)

        $path = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($FilePath)
        $fileName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)

        $shellAppType = [Type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application")
        $shellAppInst = [Activator]::CreateInstance($shellAppType)
        $directory = $shellAppInst.NameSpace($path)
        $link = $directory.ParseName($fileName)
        $verbs = $link.Verbs()
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $verbs.Count; ++$i) {
            $verb = $verbs.Item($i)
            Write-Host $verb.Name
            if ($verb.Name.Equals($localizedVerb)) {
                $verb.DoIt()
                return $true
            }
        }
        return $false
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "File '$FilePath' does not exist"
    }
}
```

**Script in action on a vanilla Win7 machine**

[image: Showing script in action]

Comment: DAXaholic, thanks for the direction. However, I am still getting an error. 
(0) : Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll' could not be found. 
FWIW, this is in PS 2.0 & Windows 7 Home, if that might make a difference. And running in the ISE, though ultimately it will run as a script.

Comment: But your first snippet works right? I guess we might need to get rid of the dynamic stuff as this causes the dependency on the missing Dll. I will try to reproduce (on Win10 & PS5 it worked) and fix it and come back once done

Comment: I was getting the same error when using dlls in the assemblies too. I have tried using $($env:path) in $assemblies as well, to no avail.

Comment: That was where I had ended up, but it still fails. If I cut and paste your example (with only the one assembly) I get a number of errors, the first being
The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or a
n assembly reference?)
I get a similar error about the dynamic type, and it seems like both might be defined in the C# dll, but when I include that I get the dll not found error.

Comment: It is because you are bound to the older versions of .NET / C#  
I rewrote your script so it should work in that environment by 'converting' some of the C# code to PowerShell which IMHO is anyway not that bad in this case

Comment: ,I did indeed get it working, thanks for the input. My only worry is that the next step may need to be pure C#. Namely, I want to now implement this:
http://alexweinberger.com/main/pinning-network-program-taskbar-programmatically-windows-10/
But using inlined C# rather than compiling to an external executable. Weekend work.

Comment: In my language version of Windows, the contents of mscorlib.dll do not correspond well to the names of COM objects executed by the $ verb.DoIt () function. Are you sure this is the correct dll?

Comment: Localized strings 5386 and 5387 are not issued to me by the COM library. although mscorlib.dll looks like it gives the correct lines. ... Perhaps due "Classic Start Menu" installed on my computer'.

Comment: As a result of this discrepancy between the names of com and mscorlib.dll, I can not start anything of the remaining launch options .